# Access ASPX variable in ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Below is a code in my aspx page. I have declared an aspx variable called connect.  I would like to pass it in my SqlDataSource control in the attribute ConnectionString however, I am getting an error in the page that says Keyword not supported: '<%'

```
<%
    Dim environmentText = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT")
    Dim connString As String = "GymsConnectionString"

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentText) Then 
        environmentText = environmentText.ToLower().Trim()
        connString = String.Format("GymsConnectionString_{0}", environmentText)
    End If 

    Dim connect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connString).ToString()
%>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%
    =connect %>"
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Table1] WHERE ([ColumnID] = @ColumnID)">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:SessionParameter Name="Column_ID" Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just directly set it. No need to use markup to embed it.

```
SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString = connect
```

Comment: Hi Jason, I am aware of it. But the aspx page already calls this connect variable. I just want to make it working via the aspx page. I don't want to set it from code behind.

Comment: @pierro-makroth The name is Mason, not Jason. This doesn't have to be done in the code behind, it can be done in your code block that you already have on the ASPX page.

Comment: can you please paste the code here? What will be the changes that needs to be done for asp:SqlDataSource control ConnectionString attribute?

Comment: @pierro-makroth It's in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I had it working.

In the aspx page, I removed the ConnectionString attribute and also removed the block of code below in the aspx page:

Dim environmentText = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT")
    Dim connString As String = "GymsConnectionString"

```
If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentText) Then 
    environmentText = environmentText.ToLower().Trim()
    connString = String.Format("GymsConnectionString_{0}", environmentText)
End If 

Dim connect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connString).ToString()
```

Then in the code behind, I set the control connection string in Page load:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    Dim environmentText = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ENVIRONMENT")
    Dim connString As String = "GymsConnectionString"

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(environmentText) Then 
        environmentText = environmentText.ToLower().Trim()
        connString = String.Format("GymsConnectionString_{0}", environmentText)
    End If 

    Dim connect As String = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(connString).ToString()

    SqlDataSource1.ConnectionString=connect
    SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString=connect
```